# Karate API - Regular exp for numbers[0-9] or null

Tags: regex, api, karate

I am trying this below regular exp in karate api automation to check the field value is numeric[0-9] or null value. but its not giving correct results. Can anyone help on this ?

The regular exp is `'#regex (?:[0-9]{1}|null)'`

Example : From the below JSON sometimes sisters/brothers response will be integers or null. So I want to validate with regex to ensure it has integers/null data.

"info": {
"Name": Tomas,
"Age": 29,
"Sisters": 1,
"Brothers": null,

```
    }
```

Comment: Regex is not used to check for null values. Maybe you need `name: '#notnull'` and a regex like `'#regex [0-9]+'`?

Comment: to OP - you are missing a short example JSON of what you are trying to validate. edit your question, else I'm sorry no one can help you.

Comment: Hi Peter Thomas, from the below JSON sometimes sisters/brothers response will be integers or null so I want to validate with regex to ensure it has integers/null data.

"info": {
            "Name": Tomas,
            "Age": 29,
            "Sisters": 1,
            "Brothers": null,
   
  }

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew, it is not working

Answer (score -1):

I found the answer, the below reg exp is working

- match response.info.sisters == '##regex [0-9]{1}'

thanks

Comment: I don't think that is correct